# Simple MYSQL Update query wont work

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I wanna update a table based on a single thing however it wont do it at all.

Define **$refid**

```
$result =mysql_query("SELECT ref from user WHERE id=".$_SESSION['sess_data']['usrid']) or die(mysql_error());
    if( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    { $refid = $row['ref']; } else { /* N/A */ }
```

Now that we have it we do the query :

```
  if ($refid != 0) { // If referrer else than 0 (true in my case) do :
        $resins1 = mysql_query("update user set toref=toref+0.5 where id=".$_SESSION['sess_data']['usrid']); 
        $resins2 = mysql_query("update user set credits=credits+0.5 where id='$refid'"); 
        }
```

It's funny because the 1st query work without any problem. I have one more query like **$resins2** and works as well. The **toref** tabel is updated but the **credits** is not.

---

Seems like the query doesn't accept 0.5 values on second query so changed to 1. ( MYSQL table accepts ). It's not a real fix but it works.

Thank you guys for help.

Comment: Do you checked mysql error? Do you dumped $resins2?

Comment: Two things. First, `echo` out the query that is not working and place that into something like PHPMyAdmin. Second, do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. If at all possible, use `PDO`. If for whatever reason you cannot use `PDO`, use `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: Is `$refid` the same as `$_SESSION['sess_data']['usrid']`

Comment: @Mamuz no Mysql Error and not sure

Comment: Where is your error checking? You wouldn't know if something went wrong - you're not looking. Check the return value of your query, and if it's `false` look at `mysql_error()` for an error message.

Comment: @Explosion Pills no is not

Comment: I check'd for mysql error $resins2 = mysql_query("update user set credits=credits+0.5 where id='$refid'") or die "error"; and nothing

Comment: When you have no mysql error, then your query is valid. Maybe your query will update no record cause on condition.

Comment: All condition are fine. refid is not 0, the refid query works ( tested with echo ).

Comment: can you post your table structure? If credits field's datatype is integer it doesn't accept 0.5 value.

Comment: Accepts 0.5 or any .... even 8.59996e+07 = 85999600 ...